# MVC Javascript and AJAX, checbox onchange()

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am building a simple MVC project and I need to use the checkbox method on change and get the bool value to use in the method of my controller.

The method in the controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetValidUser(bool Checkbox)
    {
        List<Users> userData = new List<Users>();
        connection();
        con.Open();
        var d = new DataTable();
        //bool valid = bool.Parse(Request.Form.GetValues("Category").ToString());
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Checkbox)
                    is_active = true;
                else if (!Checkbox)
                    is_active = false;
                userData = Getdatatabletolist("GetActiveUsers");
                return View(userData);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Users are here";
            return View(userData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Can't get users";
            return View(userData);
        }
    }
```

and its view

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationIntro.Models.Users>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetValidUser";
}
<h2>GetValidUser</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.is_active)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.is_active)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The main view called Test view

```
 @using WebApplicationIntro.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "tableBody"
    };
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody id="tableBody">
            @Html.Action("GetValidUser", new { Checkbox = false })
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(alert("jquery is working"));
    </script>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetValidUser", ajaxOpts))
    {
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBox("AutoCalculateMandate", false, new { onchange = "javascript:$(this.form).submit();" })
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

How to get the bool value of the checkbox and pass it to the method? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Change your method signature to

public ActionResult GetValidUser(bool AutoCalculateMandate)

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting your form and the variable 'Checkbox' will not hold the value of whether the checkbox checked or not. Only AutoCalculateMandate will hold the value of check action.
Change your method to

```js
  
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetValidUser(bool AutoCalculateMandate)
{
    List<Users> userData = new List<Users>();
    connection();
    con.Open();
    var d = new DataTable();
    //bool valid = bool.Parse(Request.Form.GetValues("Category").ToString());
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Checkbox)
                is_active = true;
            else if (!Checkbox)
                is_active = false;
            userData = Getdatatabletolist("GetActiveUsers");
            return View(userData);
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Users are here";
        return View(userData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Can't get users";
        return View(userData);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method I am using is to get a list from the database, replacing get with post will lead to httpException!

Comment: Do you have a view associated with GetValidUser?
Can you please provide the details of that httpexception.?

Comment: on this line : @Html.Action("GetValidUser", new { AutoCalculateMandate = false })      



Inner Exception 1:
HttpException: Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information.

Inner Exception 2:
HttpException: A public action method 'GetValidUser' was not found on controller 'WebApplicationIntro.Controllers.DBController'.

and you can find the view of GetValidUser in my question

Comment: I dont know whats  logic of using Html.Action with same method name here.
Better you separate the @Html.Action("GetValidUser", new { AutoCalculateMandate = false }) with some other name and seperate your common functionality for both submit and Html.Action in another method to access.

Comment: I am a little bit new to MVC, the Html.Action is to get the view of the method GetValidUser  and place it in the table of the test view, can you please edit my code in the question to inform me what d you mean by separate them

Comment: 1. First of all pass the datatable value to modal and bind it in the view, No need to use the Html.Action.

2. What is the purpose of checkbox? To load data again?

whats the name of the VIew GetValidUser .cshtml ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187119/discussion-between-ratheesh-and-mohammad-anouti).